# How to convert (Integer, Int, Int ) to Day. Couldn't match expected type ‘Day’ with actual type ‘(Integer, Int, Int)’

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  Prelude.putStrLn "Please,enter date YYYY-MM-DD"
  currentTime <- getCurrentTime
  date <- Prelude.getLine
  let sTime = show currentTime 
  let retrievedDate = toGregorian $ utctDay currentTime
  let forecastDay = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%-m-%-d" date :: Maybe Day
  let diifedDays = diffDays (fromJust forecastDay) retrievedDate
  if date >= show retrievedDate && diifedDays > 0 && diifedDays <= 16 
     then print date
     else print "Time Error!"
```

I need retrievedDate (Integer,Int,Int) conver to Day.
The task is: subtract from (forecastDay - retrievedDay)
But I can not do this, since I need retrievedDate convert to Day

Error Message: 
 Couldn't match expected type ‘Day’
                  with actual type ‘(Integer, Int, Int)’

42 |  let diifedDays = diffDays (fromJust forecastDay) retrievedDate

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem type Day from Data.Time
I need convert (Integer,Int,Int) --->>>> Day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to fix your error is simply remove `toGregorian` and it will typecheck just fine.

You might want to work on your logic though.

Answer (score 2):

Well actually you already got a `Day` object, but by using `toGregorian`, you convert it into a triple `(Integer, Int, Int)` (the year, month, day according to the *Gregorian* calendar). So you can actually just drop the `toGregorian` function call:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  Prelude.putStrLn "Please,enter date YYYY-MM-DD"
  currentTime <- getCurrentTime
  date <- Prelude.getLine
  let sTime = show currentTime 
  let retrievedDate = utctDay currentTime
  let forecastDay = parseTimeM True defaultTimeLocale "%Y-%-m-%-d" date :: Maybe Day
  let diifedDays = diffDays (fromJust forecastDay) retrievedDate
  if date >= show retrievedDate && diifedDays > 0 && diifedDays <= 16 
     then print date
     else print "Time Error!"
```

If you however need to convert the triple back, you can use the [**`fromGregorian :: Integer -> Int -> Int -> Day`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.1/docs/Data-Time-Calendar.html#v:fromGregorian) function. For a triple `(Integer, Int, Int)`, we can thus use:

```
\(y, m, d) -> fromGregorian y m d
```

Besides that your code makes however a rather chaotic impression with a lot of `let` statements, `show`s, etc. So I would really advice you to clean it up.